# Boolean Simplification of a large problem

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am unsure where to even start on this problem. My intuition that what ever can be done to the original problem can be done over and over to simplify the whole thing. Please help with some guidance.

$ (a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot d) + (a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot \overline{d}) + (a \cdot b \cdot \overline{c} \cdot d) + (a \cdot b \cdot \overline{c} \cdot \overline{d}) + (a \cdot \overline{b} \cdot c \cdot d) + (a \cdot \overline{b} \cdot c \cdot \overline{d}) + (a \cdot \overline{b} \cdot d) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $(a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d)+(a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot \overline d)=a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot(d+\overline d)=a\cdot b\cdot c$. There are several other places where you can apply that same idea.

Comment: Okay, I've gotten this far and checked the truth table to know it's still logically equivalent:
$a \cdot b + a \cdot \overline{b} \cdot c + a \cdot \overline{b} \cdot d $

Can this be simplified further? I don't understand the distributive property enough to know what to do when there are not all of the same variables like in your example.

Comment: @Jexoteric: That looks irreducible to me. Distributivity would let you write it as $a\cdot b+a\cdot\overline b(c+d)$ or as $a\cdot(b+\overline b\cdot(c+d))$, but I wouldn’t call either of those a simplification.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I guess $\cdot$ denotes conjunction [`AND`] and $+$ disjunction [`OR`]. Use the *distributivity laws* 
$$\begin{aligned}
X\cdot Y+X\cdot Z&\,=\,X\cdot(Y+Z)\\
(X+Y)\cdot(X+Z)&\,=\,X+(Y\cdot Z)\,.
\end{aligned}$$